# Creating an Oracle materialized view takes 6 minutes but refresh takes 42 minutes, why?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, refresh, materialized-views

Thanks in advance if you can solve this problem.

I'm running on an Oracle 11g r2 database and I'm building a new materialized view and although the creation of the view only takes around 6 minutes to create, when I come to refresh it every day it takes around 42 minutes. The procedure REFRESH_ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV to refresh this code is below and the code that creates the materialized view is at the bottom. Is there something i'm doing wrong??

When I just do a simple refresh using code below it takes 25 minutes.

```
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML';
    dbms_mview.REFRESH('ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV');
end;
/
```

But the procedure below takes 42 minutes. I don't understand why it's taking much longer to refresh than the creation of the materialized view?? and why both refreshes are so wide apart in terms of time it takes to refresh.

```
PROCEDURE REFRESH_ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV
IS
   l_method VARCHAR2(1) := 'C';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML';
   Dbms_Mview.Refresh(LIST=>'ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV', 
   METHOD=>l_method, atomic_refresh=>FALSE, PARALLELISM=>8); 

END REFRESH_ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV;
```

The code that creates the materialized view below.

```
PROMPT Drop MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV
-- create create MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV;
-- create create MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV
PROMPT Create MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV (SUPPLIER,
                                             BROADCASTER,
                                             PRODUCTION_TITLE,
                                             PRODUCTION_NUMBER,
                                             SERIES_TITLE,
                                             SUPPLIED_SOURCE_IND,
                                             THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID,
                                             BRO_BROADCAST_BY_TP_SURR_ID,
                                             STATION_ID                                         
                                             )                                           
TABLESPACE PRBLK_MV_BD_A
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
NOCACHE
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT )
BUILD IMMEDIATE
USING INDEX
            TABLESPACE PRBLK_MV_BI_A
            PCTFREE    10
            INITRANS   2
            MAXTRANS   255
            STORAGE    (
                        INITIAL          64K
                        NEXT             1M
                        MINEXTENTS       1
                        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                        PCTINCREASE      0
                        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                       )
REFRESH ON DEMAND
WITH ROWID
AS 
/* Formatted on Mon/06/02/2017 10:07:52 (QP5 v5.267.14150.38573) */
select x.supplier_name as supplier , 
       x.broadcaster_name as broadcaster , 
       ptle.title as production_title , 
       x.production_number as production_number , 
       stle.title as series_title , 
       x.production_source as supplied_source_ind , 
       x.third_party_group_id , 
       x.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id,
       x.STATION_ID
FROM
(select usages.production_number,
       usages.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id,
       usages.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id,
       usages.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID,
       usages.SUPPLIER_NAME,
       usages.THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID,
       usages.STATION_ID,
       usages.BROADCASTER_NAME,
       prod.cre_surr_id,
       prod.production_source,
       prod.prod_series_cre_surr_id
from productions prod,
(SELECT --+ parallel(uh)
       uh.production_number, 
       uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id,
       uh.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id,
       supplier_details.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID,
       supplier_details.SUPPLIER_NAME,
       supplier_details.THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID,
       supplier_details.STATION_ID,
       supplier_details.BROADCASTER_NAME,
       row_number() over(partition by uh.production_number order by uh.production_number) prod_rows
FROM usage_headers uh,
        (SELECT third_party.surr_id AS THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID, 
                third_party.supplier_name as SUPPLIER_NAME,
                third_party.supplier_group_id AS THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID, 
                third_party.dn_root_tp_surr_id AS THIRD_PARTY_ROOT_ID, 
                bro.station_id AS STATION_ID, 
                bro.dn_tp_name AS BROADCASTER_NAME
         FROM   broadcasters bro,
                    (SELECT tp.surr_id, 
                            tp.name AS supplier_name, 
                            tp.tp_surr_id AS supplier_group_id, 
                            tp.dn_root_tp_surr_id 
                    FROM third_parties tp 
                    CONNECT BY PRIOR tp.surr_id = tp.tp_surr_id 
                    START WITH tp.surr_id IN (SELECT surr_id FROM ETL_ACQUIRED_MASTER WHERE NVL(exclude_flag,'N') <> 'Y')) third_party 
        WHERE third_party.surr_id = bro.tp_surr_id) supplier_details
WHERE uh.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id = supplier_details.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID
AND uh.production_number IS NOT NULL
AND uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id IS NOT NULL
AND uh.right_type IN ('M', 'B')
AND NVL (uh.dn_uls_usage_status, '3') NOT IN ('9', '11')
AND uh.udg_surr_id IS NOT NULL
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM prblk.production_usage_components puc 
                 WHERE puc.uh_surr_id = uh.surr_id 
                 AND PUC.DISTRIBUTION_STATUS IS NOT NULL)) usages
WHERE usages.prod_rows = 1
AND usages.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id 
AND prod.production_source <> 'AP') x
LEFT OUTER JOIN titles ptle ON ( ptle.cre_surr_id = x.cre_surr_id AND ptle.tt_code = 'R') 
LEFT OUTER JOIN titles stle ON ( stle.cre_surr_id = x.prod_series_cre_surr_id AND stle.tt_code = 'R');

COMMENT ON MATERIALIZED VIEW ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV IS 'snapshot of none acquired productions - ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV';

PROMPT select on 'ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV' to APPS_ACCESS_ROLE_BLK
GRANT SELECT ON ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV TO APPS_ACCESS_ROLE_BLK;
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
exec dbms_mview.refresh('ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV', 'C', atomic_refresh=>false);
```

The atomic refresh of false means it will truncate then insert. If using atomic refresh, it will do a transactional delete + insert (the default I believe).  "Safer" but can be much longer to complete.

Of course, its not guaranteed to always take the same time to complete the refresh.  For example, if you have a lot of other processes running at the same time (competing for resources), you may experience "slowness" compared to other runtimes.

Also, if someone else is accessing that snapshot table in a long running transaction, you may be blocked for a while trying to do a complete refresh (using atomic_refresh=>false).  So perhaps check for blocking locks if its taking a while.

Comment: Hi @tbone try doing dbms_mview.refresh('ACTIVE_NON_ACQU_MV', 'C', atomic_refresh=>false); but my procedure is doing this already